# Converting C char array (unsafe pointer) to String

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I have an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>` filled by a CoreFoundation method.

If I NSLog it with `%s` placeholder, it outputs just fine.

But if I try with Swift's `print` it just writes the memory address.

Tried nearly everything... also I don't understand why if I try to access the underlying `memory` property I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
let deviceName = UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>.alloc(64)

/* other statements in which deviceName is filled */

NSLog("device %s by %s", deviceName, manufacturerName)
// Outputs correctly the string

print(String(deviceName[0]))
// Get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime

print(String(deviceName.memory))
// Get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime

let str = withUnsafePointer(&deviceName) { String.fromCString(UnsafePointer($0)) }
print(str)
// Outputs an empty string

print("\(deviceName) by \(manufacturerName)")
// Outputs just memory addresses
```

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code, please? What's in this pointer, what are you doing, what result are you after, and what happens when you try?

Comment: So may I assume that it is in fact a C string?

Comment: @matt Yes, `deviceName` is in fact a C NUL-terminated char array

Comment: And you've tried `print(deviceName[0])` and you don't get the first letter? That makes me think you don't really have this C string after all. You couldn't show how you got hold of it?

Comment: I would expect a C string to be an UnsafePointer<Int8>. I don't see how it could be an UnsafePointer<Character>.

Comment: I think we've established that you're not willing to show your actual code. It is crucial to know why you think this would be an UnsafePointer<Character> and how you populated it, but you seem not to want to reveal that. Plus, this is a very odd way to get hold of a C string in Swift. Why won't you show where this device name _really_ comes from?

Comment: Maybe there's another error in my code, but the thing I know is that NSLog success in logging that string!

Comment: I can show all the code, it's not a secret, it's just a bit long. The string is the name of an Audio device installed on the current machine.

Comment: But that is because NSLog ignores how you incorrectly typed `deviceName` to start with. It just looks at the contents of memory. But Swift can't do that.

Comment: `AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceIDs[idx], &deviceAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize, deviceName)` is the line that fills the deviceName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem unwilling to show your code, so I can't really help. But this looks just wrong:

```
let deviceName = UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>.alloc(64)
/* other statements in which deviceName is filled */
```

That is not how to get hold of a C string in Swift, and if you believe that it *is* a C string in Swift, you're wrong; it would need to be an array of Int8 (C characters), not Swift Character (a struct!), to be a C string.

In other words, C char (your question's title) is not Swift Character - they are *nothing* like one another. A C char is a small number, a Swift Character is an object in an object-oriented language that C knows nothing about!

Comment: Please read in the comment above. If you want I can copy the entire code, it's just a bit long. I reported the line that fills the array.

Comment: I've told you what you need to know. I don't know what AudioObjectGetPropertyData does but no way in the world would it provide a C array of Swift Character.

Comment: Ok, now I tried with Int8, and printing `deviceName[0]` results in 66 that is ascii-code for uppercase B, for "Built-in Microphone"

Comment: For future references, this code will generate the Swift string: `String.fromCString(deviceName)!`

Comment: Thanks for your help!